# is it possible to open Settings App using openURL?

Tags: iphone, settings

I know an app can launch other apps by using this code: `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:appUrl];`. And I know the scheme of URL to open safari and mail, but I did some searches and found nothing about the scheme of settings.app.

Comment: I think [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/377102/how-do-i-open-the-settings-application-from-my-application) answers it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Opening the Settings app from another app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5655674/opening-the-settings-app-from-another-app)

Comment: Check this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28152526/how-do-i-open-phone-settings-when-a-button-is-clicked-ios/34024467#34024467

Answer (score 34):

You can open settings apps programmatically try this(works only from **iOS8** onwards).

If you are using Swift:

```
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString))
```

If you are using Objective-C

```
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString]];
```

For other lower versions(less than **iOS8**) its not possible to programatically open settings app.

Comment: Big thumbs up! This is great. I tested on iOS 7.1 and it crashed the app, sure enough, when running iOS 8 it takes you to Apple Settings

Comment: is there a way to open to the General Settings app (top-level), not drilled down to your own App Settings?

Comment: This was renamed to `UIApplication.openSettingsURLString`.

Answer (score 17):

You can use this in iOS versions 5.0 - 5.0.1. It was then deprecated in iOS 5.1.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs://"]];
```

Answer (score 3):

Opening settings apps programmatically is possible only from iOS 8. So, use the following code from http://code-ios.blogspot.in/2014/10/opening-settings-app-from-another-app.html

```
if([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]&&
   [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] != kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied)
{
  //...Location service is enabled
}
else
{
    if([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue]<8.0)
    {
    UIAlertView* curr1=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"This app does not have access to Location service" message:@"You can enable access in Settings->Privacy->Location->Location Services" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [curr1 show];
    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertView* curr2=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"This app does not have access to Location service" message:@"You can enable access in Settings->Privacy->Location->Location Services" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:@"Settings", nil];
        curr2.tag=121;
        [curr2 show];
    }
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
 NSLog(@"buttonIndex:%d",buttonIndex);

   if (alertView.tag == 121 && buttonIndex == 1)
 {
  //code for opening settings app in iOS 8
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL  URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString]];
 }
}
```

Comment: Although the user doesn't have much control over it, you may want to add a check for [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] != kCLAuthorizationStatusRestricted

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4** version:

```
if let url = URL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString) {
    UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
}
```