# open application setting page in iOS 6 and 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsurl, uiapplication

In `iOS 8` there is now a settings launch URL to send the user directly to the settings page of an App

```
if(&UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString != nil)
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString]];
}
```

My question is how to open application setting page in `iOS 6` and `iOS 7` directly from application like in 'iOS 8'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to open `Setting` screen of iOS Device(unjailbreak), below the iOS 8.0, This new feature is only available from iOS8.

You can check as per you are doing, for support of `UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString` URI for iOS.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Agreed, this API was only introduced in iOS 8. There was an undocumented way of doing this in iOS 5, but that was patched in iOS 6.

Comment: @ViralSavaj this is duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15682164/iphone-open-settings-from-my-application-ios-6