# Can we invoke the first time permissions asked for calendar/Albums access in iOS7 again?

Tags: ios, ios7

I am testing an iOS native app on iOS7, which has a feature that access the calendar/album feature of the phone. On accessing the calendar or albums first time it asks the user for the permission, with allow and don't allow. if we click don't allow and exit the app and then again launch the app and try to invoke the calendar or albums, its neither giving me the Allow/Don't allow prompt not permitting me to access calendar/photos.

My question is that is there any way we can invoke the the allow/don't allow prompt the second time when the app is launched, if the user has clicked on Don't allow the first time.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no. You can however check if the app has access and if not, prompt the user to enable it on the app settings page and then redirect them to it where they can change it.

Instructions on how to open the app settings page

[is it possible to open Settings App using openURL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090373/is-it-possible-to-open-settings-app-using-openurl)