# Is it possible to open Settings App using URL (Deep link) on Android?

Tags: android, android-intent, deep-linking

It is possible to do on iOS like this: (find [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24570712/1832221))

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString]];
```

> Is there an equivalent on Android?

Something like that maybe?

```
String url = "app-settings:";
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no URLs for Settings AFAIK.

However, [the `Settings` class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html) provides dedicated action strings for the Settings app and many of the screens inside of it.

So, to open up the Settings app's main screen, it would be:

```
startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS));
```