# How to open device Settings to login in to Twitter and Facebook from Social.Framework?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook, twitter, social-networking

Im using Social.Framework for sharing app specific info to Facebook as well as Twitter everything is working except, if user is not already logged in to Facebook and Twitter in his device that time I want to show a message like login to these sites in device settings and I need to navigate user to Device Settings on tap of this button, my apps minimum deployment target is iOS 6.0 and above, How to take user to Apps Settings Screen from my app?

I heard that openURL is not allowed by Apple from iOS5.0 and above, so that I cant even use the below snippet,

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs:root=TWITTER"]];
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4092162/how-can-i-open-the-settings-app-when-the-user-presses-a-button check this link

Comment: possible duplicate of [Opening the Settings app from another app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5655674/opening-the-settings-app-from-another-app)

Comment: This question has been asked many times. Please do a quick search before asking new questions. Voting to close a duplicate.

Comment: this is a different question