# linking to Settings/General/Location Service directly from app

Tags: iphone

If a user starts my application and initially elects not to allow location services, I would like to prompt the user to reconsider with a UIAlertMessage ("Update" and "No, Thanks."). "No, Thanks." would be a simple cancel, and I would like "Update" to link them directly to Settings/General/Location Service (or as close as I can get).

Can anyone offer me advice on how to proceed, or where I should look for more information?

Answer (score 3):

Zak, you can't do it.  See

[How do I open the Settings application from my application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/377102/how-do-i-open-the-settings-application-from-my-application)

or

[Programmatically opening the settings app (iPhone)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/736047/programmatically-opening-the-settings-app-iphone)

Comment: Well, that is disappointing... Thank you very much for the quick response, and the links. I'm going to go ahead and leave this unanswered, just in case this Apple opens this up in an upcoming release. I will vote you "up" instead. Thanks! Z@K!

Comment: While you can't take them to the settings, you can of course still show a dialog on opening the app to say something like this:"You have currently disabled location services for this app. By doing this you're missing out on some great features that come with this app! If you change your mind, you can enable it by going to settings > general > location services. Thanks!".  However, bear in mind that users who have disabled the location service probably already know what they're doing and are unlikely to be swayed by an alert!...