# Possible to open up Settings App from my application?

Tags: iphone, ipad, settings

I want to bring user to the option, where he/she can turn off Multitasking gestures on his/her iPad.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't do that. However as an alternative you can use [This Framework](http://www.inappsettingskit.com/) to mimmick the settings app, so that you can set your settings from the official settings app, or from a in app settings page.

Also look into this link. This will tell you in detail about your problem.[How do I open the Settings application from my application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/377102/how-do-i-open-the-settings-application-from-my-application)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get all the way in to the multi tasking gestures settings, but you can get some steps into the settings...

Have a look at the list of urls you can use to get to the settings from your app here:
http://www.mokten.com/2011/11/ios-5-custom-url-for-settings-app/

As Maulik says, you can use this code with the appropriate url to get there:
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs://"]];