# Open setting from my app

Tags: ios, ipad, ios5, icloud

I am using iCloud for core data. if user is not logged in on iCloud i want to take him to setting page, is it possible in ios.

Thanks

Comment: This question has effectively been asked (and answered) on SO many times before ([here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090373/is-it-possible-to-open-settings-app-using-openurl), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/377102/how-do-i-open-the-settings-application-from-my-application), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5655674/opening-the-settings-app-from-another-app) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9627451/how-to-open-prefrences-settings-with-ios-5-1) for example). Please check previous questions/answers before posting a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are writing app for iOS < 5.1 then you can use custom URL schemes - find list [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8246814/194544).

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: myUrlString ]]; //find myUrlString in link above
```

But this feature was removed in iOS 5.1 and most likely won't available in the feature